# Plugin for Outlook to show the picture of sender (in C#)

Tags: c#, .net, outlook-addin

The following are the two tasks I want to accomplish:

1. I want to import all the contact details including the image from the intranet site to Outlook. (I think this part, I can easily handle by crawling the directory)
2. Convert this program into a plugin so that everyone can install.

I am planning to write this using C#. Can you give me some pointers on how to get started and what type of project this is going to be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've made an plugin that works exacly how you describe. For outlook 2007.

Basically, I just created a solution in VS with template "Outlook Add-in" (for office 2007 or 2010 depending on your situation).

At startup I create a custom menu item that will trigger an import. Example available (for 2003 but it's kind of the same procedure) at:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms269110(v=vs.80).aspx

In order to display a picture of the sender I created Outlook contact items into a custom contacts folder to avoid messing up the the "original" contacts folder. Then I had to mark this folder as an "Outlook Address Book" (which is not default), otherwise Outlook won't consider this folder when trying to find a contact picture.

Below is a link with a description of how to create custom contacts folder and contact items:

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/97/10159686/creating-folder-in-outlook-using-c.aspx

To mark it as an address book, there is a property on the folder object called something like IsAddressBook..I don't really remember exactly but you'll probably find out. :)

Comment: Thanks a bunch Ozzy, Will let you know how it went.